# Bluetooth connection problem

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I am using Arduino Uno and Blue tooth HC-06, I am trying to use this in order to switch a LED through mt phone but I cannot create communication  between the Bluetooth and the Arduino, I am using software version 1.8.13 and I manage to pair to the Bluetooth through my phone, this is my code:

```
    char data = 0;                //Variable for storing received data
    void setup() 
    {
    Serial.begin(9600);         //Sets the data rate in bits per second (baud) for serial data transmission
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);        //Sets digital pin 13 as output pin
    }
    void loop()
    {
    if(Serial.available() > 0)  // Send data only when you receive data:
    {
    data = Serial.read();      //Read the incoming data and store it into variable data
    Serial.print(data);        //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor
    Serial.print("\n");        //New line 
    if(data == '1')            //Checks whether value of data is equal to 1 
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);  //If value is 1 then LED turns ON
    else if(data == '0')       //Checks whether value of data is equal to 0
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);   //If value is 0 then LED turns OFF
    }    

                        

}
```

and this is the image of the wiring:
[image]

I don't have any problem with the computer the software or the Arduino different codes I can run very easily the only problem is with the Bluetooth device

Thanks a lot

Comment: With what app your you trying to send the serial data? Are you using Andriod? The HC-06 will only be connected, if the app starts and holds the connection. So you cannot just connect the HC-06 just in the Andriod bluetooth settings. That is only for pairing. The actual connection is initiated by the app. Thats what I already stumbed across myself.